# How to save content of RichTextBox in BlockUIContainer, to RTF file?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, richtextbox

I made two richtexbox, one small richtexbox nested in a big richtextbox by using BlockUIContainer, see XAML file below.

```
    <RichTextBox IsDocumentEnabled="True"  x:Name="first" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="174" Margin="120,136,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="254" TextChanged="first_TextChanged" MouseDoubleClick="first_MouseDoubleClick">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text="RichTextBox"/>
            </Paragraph>
            <BlockUIContainer>
                <RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="second"  MouseDoubleClick="second_MouseDoubleClick" Width="239" TextChanged="second_TextChanged">
                    <FlowDocument>
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text="RichTextBox1"/>
                            <Run Language="en" Text="hh"/>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </FlowDocument>
                </RichTextBox>
            </BlockUIContainer>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
```

I want contents of both richtexbox saved in a RTF file. Normally we can use  TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd), since now we have nested richtexbox, so i think TextRange is probablly not working. And maybe i will add some images in the richtextbox, so I want to try binary stream, see below. "first" is the name of big richtextbox. THE PATH is the path for RTF file.

```
FlowDocument document = first.Document;
System.IO.Stream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(document, ms);
byte[] data = new byte[ms.Length];
ms.Position = 0;
ms.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
ms.Close();
File.WriteAllBytes(THE PATH, data);
```

But in the saved RTF file, when i open it, it shows like this,

```
<FlowDocument PagePadding="5,0,5,0" AllowDrop="True"    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"> <Paragraph>RichTextBox</Paragraph><Paragraph><Run xml:lang="en">test test test!!!</Run></Paragraph><BlockUIContainer><RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True" Name="second" Width="239"><FlowDocument PagePadding="5,0,5,0" AllowDrop="True"><Paragraph>RichTextBox1<Run xml:space="preserve"> </Run><Run xml:lang="en">hhthis is a small richtextbox</Run></Paragraph><Paragraph><Run xml:lang="en" xml:space="preserve" /></Paragraph></FlowDocument></RichTextBox></BlockUIContainer></FlowDocument>
```

I don´t want to see XAML plain text in the saved file, I want it to show like a normal word document, see below. and probably also see the border line of the small richtextbox (this border line doesnot show below)

```
RichTextBox
test test test!!!
RichTextBox1 hhthis is a small richtextbox
```

What should I do? or nested richtextbox by BlockUIContainer is not possible to show like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by saving it and specifying the format. I omit the unnecessary code, but just replace memorystream with what you currently have.

```
richTextBox.SelectAll();
richTextBox.Selection.Save(new MemoryStream(), DataFormats.Rtf);
```

`XamlWriter` will save it as a XAML format

Comment: Thanks lll, by using DataFormats.Rtf, the text of the big richtextbox is shown in the file, but the small richtextbox is totally disappeared. I am thinking maybe this way can not handle stuff inside BlockUIContainer...

XamlWriter can keep stuff inside BlockUIContainer, but i donot know how to make the stream correctly shown in the saved file...

Comment: Why don't you grab the Richtextbox's document, get the block then remove the BlockUIContainer and readd it to the Flowdocument